# Centering a plot within a fluidRow in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, centering

I have a fluidRow with a plot rendered in one of the columns.  I would like to know how to center the plot when I have manually specified the plot width via the renderPlot({create plot here}, width = ##) function (thus, it doesn't take up the full width of the column).

ui.R code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Nate/Documents/R Working Directory/appFolder/example")
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Test"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
p('stuff here')
  ),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(id = 'tabs1',
          tabPanel("main",
                   fluidRow(
                     column(8,
                            plotOutput('plot1')),
                     column(4,
                            p('2nd column'))),
                   fluidRow(
                   p("2nd row of viewing area"))
                   ),

          tabPanel("second",
                   p("main viewing area")),
          tabPanel("third",
                          p('main viewing area')
                   )
))
)
))
```

server.R code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$text1 = renderText({
paste("text output")
})
output$plot1 = renderPlot({
x = runif(10,0,10)
y = rnorm(10)
plot(x,y)
}, width = 300)
})
```

Answer (score 77):

`align="center"` can be included within the `column` expression (not within `plotOutput` though). 
e.g.

```
fluidRow(
  column(8, align="center",
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)
```

Comment: Its missing the `offset` to actually work when there's only one element in the `fluidRow`

Comment: If your `fluidRow()` is in a `mainPanel()` and this solution still isn't helping the plot look centered, try adding an argument `width=12` to `mainPanel()` and see if that works. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score -6):

You could use `align="center"` as part of your `plotOutput()` function.  So your ui.R would like this:

ui.R

```
setwd("C:/Users/Nate/Documents/R Working Directory/appFolder/example")
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Test"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
p('stuff here')
  ),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(id = 'tabs1',
          tabPanel("main",
                   fluidRow(
                     column(8,
                            plotOutput('plot1',align="center")),
                     column(4,
                            p('2nd column'))),
                   fluidRow(
                   p("2nd row of viewing area"))
                   ),

          tabPanel("second",
               p("main viewing area")),
      tabPanel("third",
                      p('main viewing area')
                   )
))
)
))
```