# customize vertical position of the plot in the mainPanel in a sidebarLayout

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have made a shiny app using the sidebarLayout.

The app is deployed [here](https://fednem.shinyapps.io/world_development_index_shiny/) and you can find the code to create the app below my question and the data for running it [here](https://github.com/fednem/world_development_index_shiny/tree/sidebar_layout).

When I look at the app I feel that the position of the plot in the main panel (for both tabs) is a bit awkward: I would like the plot to be more toward the centre of the page, rather than high above were it is now. This would be both for aesthetic reasons and because if someone customize the annotation font size above a certain size, the y axis name end up being outside the page.

Is there a parameter that I can change to customize the position(s) of the plot(s) ?

Thank in advance

CODE:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(plotly)
load("data_for_app.RData")
test <- FALSE
min_year <- min(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions$Year)
max_year <- max(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions$Year)
indexes <- unique(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions$IndicatorName)
countries <- unique(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions$Country)
continents <- unique(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions$Continent)
regions <- unique(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions$Region)

data_by_continent <- data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions %>%
  group_by(Continent, Year, IndicatorName) %>%
  summarise(Value = mean(Value)) %>%
  ungroup(.)

data_by_region <- data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions %>%
  group_by(Region, Year, IndicatorName) %>%
  summarise(Value = mean(Value)) %>%
  ungroup(.)


ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("TimeSeries", 
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
               sliderInput("year_range", "Select the time range to plot",
                           min = min_year,
                           max = max_year, value = c(min_year, max_year), step = 1, sep=""),
               selectInput("index", "Index to plot", choices = indexes),
               selectInput("country", "Country to plot", 
                           choices = countries, selectize = TRUE, multiple = TRUE, selected = "Italy"),
               checkboxGroupInput("customize_annotation_ts", label = ("Customize Annotation"), choices = list("Customize" = "cust"),selected = NULL),
               conditionalPanel(
                 condition = "input.customize_annotation_ts == 'cust'", 
                 numericInput("font_size_ax_ts", "Select font size for the annotations", value = 15))),
             mainPanel(plotOutput("timeseries")))
    ),
    tabPanel("Relationship between indexes",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
             inputPanel(
               selectInput("x_axis", "Select the variable on the x axis",
                           choices = indexes),
               selectInput("y_axis", "Select the variable on the y axis",
                           choices = indexes), 
               selectInput("year_relation", "Select the year you want the data for",
                           choices = c(min_year:max_year),
                           selected = 1984),
               radioButtons("color_by", "Select colour code",
                            choices = c("Continent" = "Continent", "Macro Region" = "Region")),
               checkboxInput("size_pop", "scale points \n for population size ?", value = FALSE),
               actionButton("update_relation","Update plot"),
               checkboxGroupInput("customize_annotation", 
                                  label = ("Customize Annotation"), choices = list("Customize" = "cust"),selected = NULL),
               conditionalPanel(
                 condition = "input.customize_annotation == 'cust'", 
                 numericInput("font_size_ax", "Select font size for the annotations", value = 15)))),
             mainPanel(plotOutput("relation")))
    )
  )
)
)



server <- function(input,output){

  output$timeseries <- renderPlot({df <- data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions %>%
    filter(Year > input$year_range[1],  
           Year < input$year_range[2],
           IndicatorName == input$index,
           Country %in% input$country)
  validate(
    need(length(df$Value) != 0, "There are no data in the selected years for the index chosen: please change index or
         expand the time range"))
  gplot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Value, group = Country, color = Country)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
    ylab(input$index) + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          text = element_text(size = 14))
  if(length(input$customize_annotation_ts) != 0) {print(gplot + 
                                                       theme(text = element_text(size = input$font_size_ax_ts)))}
  else {(print(gplot))}})

  df_relation <- eventReactive(input$update_relation, {validate(need(data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions %>%
                                                                  filter(Year == input$year_relation,
                                                                         IndicatorName %in% c(input$x_axis, input$y_axis, "Population, total")) %>%
                                                                  nrow(.) %>% `>`(.,0), "Neither of the selected indexes have been measured for the current year,
                                                                  please select a different year or different indexes"))
  df <- data_filtered_indicators_country_partitions %>%
    filter(Year == input$year_relation,
           IndicatorName %in% c(input$x_axis, input$y_axis, "Population, total")) %>%
    split(., .$IndicatorName) %>%
    map(~spread(., IndicatorName, Value)) %>%
    reduce(left_join, by = "CountryCode") %>%
    select(-ends_with("y"))
  colnames(df)[1:6] <- colnames(df)[1:6] %>% 
    str_split(., pattern = ".x") %>%
    map_chr(~`[`(.,1))
  df})

  by_size = eventReactive(input$size_pop, {if (input$size_pop == TRUE){TRUE} else {FALSE}})

  output$relation <- renderPlot({ validate(need(isolate(input$x_axis) %in% colnames(df_relation()) & isolate(input$y_axis) %in% colnames(df_relation()), 
                                                "The combinaton of indexes chosen is not present in the dataset for the selected year"))
    if (by_size()) {
    gplot <- ggplot(data = df_relation(), aes_string(x = isolate(as.name(input$x_axis)), 
                                            y = isolate(as.name(input$y_axis)), 
                                            color = isolate(input$color_by))) + 
      geom_point(aes(size = `Population, total`)) + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            text = element_text(size = 14))
    if(length(input$customize_annotation) != 0) {print(gplot + 
                                                     theme(text = element_text(size = input$font_size_ax)))}
    else {(print(gplot))}
    } else {
              gplot <- ggplot(data = df_relation(), aes_string(x = isolate(as.name(input$x_axis)),
                                                      y = isolate(as.name(input$y_axis)), 
                                                      color = isolate(input$color_by))) + 
                geom_point(size = 2) + 
                theme_bw() + 
                theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                      panel.border = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_blank(), 
                      text = element_text(size = 14))
              if(length(input$customize_annotation) != 0) {print(gplot + 
                                                               theme(text = element_text(size = input$font_size_ax)))}
              else {(print(gplot))}}
  }

  )

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

UPDATE:

Following the link provided in the comment by @blondeclover, I have tried to create a class for having the plot in the centre of the page.
In particular I have created a class called centreAlign just after the `fluidUI` command as follow:

```
tags$head(tags$style(".centerAlign{margin:auto; width:80%}"))
```

and provided this class as an argument to the mainPanel call

```
mainPanel(plotOutput("timeseries"), class = "centerAlign"))
```

However, this does not work as I thought it would: the plot is not centered and its position vary as a function of the `width` used in defining the class.

Comment: Try adding `align = center` to `mainPanel` -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496198/8099834)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, it seems that the `align` parameter does not work for `mainPanel`. I may have to switch to a `fluidRow` layout.